# Capture screenshot with phantomjs on a page with overlay

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to capture a particular div of a website into a screenshot to facilitate some grunt work i have to do. So far i'm using this code i found on this exact same site, which is **kinda** working:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.example.org', function() {
  // being the actual size of the headless browser
  page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };

  var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector("div.example").getBoundingClientRect();
  });

  page.clipRect = {
    top:    clipRect.top,
    left:   clipRect.left,
    width:  clipRect.width,
    height: clipRect.height
  };

  page.render('google.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

This actually works, but i have 2 problems:

1) The page has an overlay on the first visit, a popup kind of window that appears on the screenshot.
2) The images are apparently downloaded as they need to be rendered (they only appear when scrolling on the webpage)

So finally i end up with something like this:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJgUi.png)

I have no experience with phantomjs, so i have no idea how i can fix this. Eliminating the overlay DIV and the somehow forcing the images to load before taking the screenshot could work, but i don't know how to actually code it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have control of the site that you are trying to scrape? i.e. the code...

Comment: There are two ways of solving this in my mind. If you have control of the target website code, then you can put callbacks in the javascript which talk to phantomjs. If you don't have control, then you will be better off using timeouts to wait for the page to finish loading everything....

Comment: Open the wep page, get the particular overlay container and change the css to `display:none` and then render the page as an image. You can also scroll down by changing the scroll position. Check the link [http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/scroll-position.html](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/scroll-position.html)

Comment: No control, any idea how to implement the scrolling? It's the only thing left, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can programmatically remove overlay elements, set page scroll position in pixels, wait a few seconds for the images to load, then make screenshot.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1440, height: 900 };

page.open('http://www.jovago.com', function() {

    // jQuery is used at the target site
    page.evaluate(function(){
        $("#overlay, #modal").remove();
    });

    // Simulate scrolling down
    page.scrollPosition = {
        top: 1400,
        left: 0
    };    

    var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelector("div.top-destinations-homepage.promo-banners-box").getBoundingClientRect();
    });

    page.clipRect = {
        top:    clipRect.top,
        left:   clipRect.left,
        width:  clipRect.width,
        height: clipRect.height
    };

    // Wait 10 seconds for images to download
    setTimeout(function(){
          page.render('jovago.png');
          phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate! Works now, i still have trouble with the page not loading the images on time, but i will try scrolling on phantomjs before taking the screenshot. Any ideas how to implement some?

You're a lifesaver, thanks!

Comment: Updated answer with code to scroll. Images are now in place: http://imgur.com/x15Js9V P.S. If the answer was useful, don't forget to upvote and accept! )

Comment: @ptolos: were you able to scroll just like the example you've posted, or did you do it dynamically? how do you scroll if you do not know the height of the page in advance? how does the screenshot look for the site https://angular.io/ ?